# 横方向に自動リサイズするinputのdirectiveをつくりたい

Tags: javascript, angularjs

はじめまして。タイトルのとおりです。AngularJSをつかって横方向に自動リサイズするinputのdirectiveをつくっています。inputにテキストが入力され自動でinputが横方向にリサイズされる処理がわかりません。 また合わせて、inputの初期値のテキスト量に応じてページロード時にinputを自動でリサイズさせておきたいです(500pxをmax-widthにしたいです)。

高さが自動でリサイズされるものは下記が実現できたのですがwidthに置き換えてもうまく動作せずに困っています。よろしくお願いします。

===

resizeInput.coffee

```
mod = angular.module('resizeInput', [])
mod.directive 'resizeInput', ->
  {
    restrict: 'A'
    require: '?ngModel'
    link: (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) ->
      HEIGHT = 25
      el = angular.element(element[0])
      el.css 'lineHeight', HEIGHT + 'px'
      el.css 'height', HEIGHT + 'px'

      resize = (e) ->
        textHeight = e.target.scrollHeight
        height = ~ ~(textHeight / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT
        el.css 'height', height + 'px'
        return

      el.on 'input', resize
      scope.$watch attrs.ngModel, (value) ->
        if value == undefined
          return
        textHeight = el[0].scrollHeight
        height = ~ ~(textHeight / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT
        el.css 'height', height + 'px'
        return
      ngModel.$parsers.unshift (viewValue) ->
        viewValue
      return

  }
```

===

edit.html

```
<input type="text" resize-input ng-model="item.text">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こういう感じでしょうか。幅計算部分は適当です。

```
angular.module('resizeInput', [])
.directive('resizeInput', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){

      scope.$watch(function(){
        return ngModel.$modelValue;
      }, function(newVal, oldVal){
        if(angular.isDefined(newVal)){
          elem.css('width', calculateWidth(newVal.length));
        }
      });

      function calculateWidth(length){
        var minWidth = 150;
        var maxWidth = 500;
        var charWidth = 6;
        var width = length * charWidth;
        return width > maxWidth? maxWidth: width < minWidth? minWidth: width;
      }
    }
  };
});
```